# How to get a specific XML format from SQL server 2014 (example provided)

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml

Ive been banging my head against a wall with this for ages - and i've finally caved.

Can any SQL / XML experts please take a look at the below and tell me the best way to get the required XML format using FOR XML (raw? / Auto? / Path?) please?

Thanks for your help

Test data

```
CREATE TABLE #CustomerData(
[Customer ID] int

, IsCustomerID bit DEFAULT 1

, Amount1 float DEFAULT 0

, Amount2 float DEFAULT 0

)





INSERT #CustomerData

SELECT *

FROM (



VALUES (12345, 1, 50, 75),

(12444, 1, 100, 100),

(12455, 1, 25, 65)



) zz ([Customer ID], IsCustomerID, Amount1, Amount2)
```

Ive tried various combinations of FOR XML RAW / FOR XML PATH and FOR XML AUTO, but nothing quite matches.

```
<Root>
  <Customers>
    <Customer Prefix="Loan">
      <Property Name="Customer ID" Value="REF_1234" IsCustomerId="True" />
      <Property Name="Amount1" Value="10" />
      <Property Name="Amount2" Value="15" />
    </Customer>
  </Customers>
</Root>
```

"Loan" is a hardcoded text flag to be applied to all entries from the above table, although there is no specific column for it.

"Customer ID"
"IsCustomerID"
"Amount1"
"Amount2"

Are all fields in a single table

Comment: What RDBMS do you use?

Comment: Hi Alexander, SQL server 2014.

Comment: So what does your source data look like? That rather critically determines what the query should look like. "All fields in a single table" is not specific enough. Is "Prefix" a column? Is "IsCustomerId" a `BIT`? As a hint, `XML PATH` supports attributes and nesting by appropriately naming columns and using `TYPE`, e.g. `SELECT (SELECT [@Name] = 'Amount1', [@Value] = Amount1 FOR XML PATH('Property'), TYPE) .. FOR XML PATH('Customer')`, but the exact query depends on your exact input table. A `CREATE TABLE` / `INSERT` would help.

Comment: Ok thanks Jeroen, the table storing the data is a simple heap with customer ID as the pk.

Comment: I will edit the request to show the create and insert shortly. Thanks for your feedback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few things:

- You do not specify where the value of `Prefix` comes from in your result, but for the query structure this doesn't matter.
- `FOR XML PATH` allows you to conjure nested elements and attributes with specific syntax ('@' for properties) and specifying `TYPE` to insert the subqueries as typed XML.
- T-SQL cannot dynamically pivot columns to rows (only statically), so you can't (easily) write a query to produce every individual column in its own child element except by writing out the columns explicitly. This is only a problem if you really do need dynamic output (i.e. the query must continue to include all columns without rewrites even if people add columns later).
- Because of the downright peculiar syntax T-SQL uses to insert `FLOAT` and `REAL` values into XML (always using scientific notation) it's usually a good idea to either not use `FLOAT`/`REAL` at all but specific integral types (with `CONVERT`), or use `FORMAT` to produce a friendlier value. Likewise, a `BIT` value will always be output as `1` or `0`, so if you need other values you'll need to provide for that yourself.

So:

```sql
SELECT (
    SELECT 
        "@Prefix" = 'Loan',
        (SELECT 
            "@Name" = 'Customer ID', 
            "@Value" = [Customer ID], 
            "@IsCustomerID" = CASE IsCustomerId WHEN 1 THEN 'True' ELSE 'False' END
         FOR XML PATH('Property'), TYPE
        ),
        (SELECT "@Name" = 'Amount1', "@Value" = FORMAT(Amount1, 'G') FOR XML PATH('Property'), TYPE),
        (SELECT "@Name" = 'Amount2', "@Value" = FORMAT(Amount2, 'G') FOR XML PATH('Property'), TYPE)
    FROM #CustomerData
    FOR XML PATH ('Customer'), ROOT('Customers'), TYPE
)
FOR XML PATH('Root')
```

It is possible to factor out the repeated mention of `Property` by using a subquery that uses `UNION ALL`:

```sql
SELECT (
    SELECT 
        "@Prefix" = 'Loan', 
        (
         SELECT * FROM (
            SELECT 
                "@Name" = 'Customer ID', 
                "@Value" = [Customer ID], 
                "@IsCustomerID" = CASE IsCustomerId WHEN 1 THEN 'True' ELSE 'False' END 
            UNION ALL
            SELECT "@Name" = 'Amount1', "@Value" = FORMAT(Amount1, 'G'), NULL 
            UNION ALL
            SELECT "@Name" = 'Amount2', "@Value" = FORMAT(Amount2, 'G'), NULL
         ) _
         FOR XML PATH('Property'), TYPE
        )
    FROM #CustomerData
    FOR XML PATH ('Customer'), ROOT('Customers'), TYPE
)
FOR XML PATH('Root')
```

I can see either of these forms being more or less readable/maintainable depending on what's likely to change.

Comment: Thanks Jeroen, that's exactly what I needed to show me the right approach. Many thanks 